# Program in C gives 0sec user time and system time

Tags: c, shell, time

please explain why the user and system time output is zero seconds and 0% cpu usage.

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h> 
#include <fcntl.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>  

int main() { 
    char c;
    int in, out; 

    in = open(“inputfile_name”, O_RDONLY); 
    out = open(“outputfile_name”, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);  

    while(read(in,&c,1) == 1) 
        write(out,&c,1);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `c` is not shell. Are you certain that `inputfile_name` exists, and contains data?

Comment: yes these both are different . and no inputfile_name exist

Comment: @ferozhaider How is your program supposed to work if no file `inputfile_name` exists? Please consider adding marginal error checking to your program.

Comment: ok thank you so much

Comment: I no input file name exists, then the first `open` returns -1 as does the first `read` (setting EBADF in the process). That terminates your while loop immediately after which there's not much left to do.

Comment: i made files and run again. still same problem

Comment: Turn off smart quotes when you're editing code. You can't use curly quotes in C programs (or most other programming languages).

Comment: i did.. but still 0 sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a program runs sufficiently fast, it may terminate before the long-term system clock (as queried with `gettimeofday` advances. On some systems, this clock has a precision of just 10 ms, so it's likely that this happens with a very brief program like yours. In this situation, the operating system reports the runtime of your program as 0 as it didn't take any time to run from the point of view of `gettimeofday`.